# MySQL 8 MBRIntersects 10 times slower than PostGIS equivalent

Tags: performance, postgis-2.0, mysql

I'm trying to migrate a PostGIS database to MySQL 8 and am having a big performance hit when it comes to MBRIntersects.

Using Mapbox to render vector tiles, I need to extract geometry intersecting some specific bounding box from a total of 80k features.

In PostGIS, using the query below I get a total execution time of *~230ms* (*~30ms* for subsequent queries, since the results are probably cached)

```
 SELECT gid, ST_AsGeoJson(geom)
 FROM table
 WHERE geom && ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(), ST_MakePoint())::geometry;
```

However, in MySQL 8, using the query below I get a total execution time of *~620ms* and no caching appears to be taking place as subsequent queries take the same amount of time.

```
SELECT gid, ST_AsGeoJson(geom)
FROM table
WHERE MBRIntersects(ST_PolygonFromText(), ST_SRID(geom, 0));
```

An `EXPLAIN` of the query above doesn't show any indexes being used. The table was created as described below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    gid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN geom MultiPolygon NOT NULL SRID 4326,
ADD SPATIAL INDEX(geom);
```

As a bonus, the PostGIS query returns 3 rows, as opposed to MySQL's which returns only 2.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to query for map tiles?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index being used you have to convert your ST_PolygonFromText() to SRID 4326 not the geom to SRID 0. That being said, at least for me this will be even slower although using an index. I don't know if this intended or a bug.

Comment: Along the weeks I've tried converting everything to SRID 4326, converting everything to SRID 0, having everything already set as SRID 4326, having everything set as SRID 0, and all variations one can think about, with no improvement on the query speed whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

`MBRIntersects` and `ST_Intersects` are broken in MySQL 8.0 (tested in 8.0.15) and are more than 10x slower compared to MySQL 5.7. For me disabling the use of the spatial index (using `IGNORE INDEX`, forcing a full table scan, speeds up my queries somewhat. See this bug report https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94655